# How to get a list from a table few rows in ascending

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm

I'm newbie to Grails and I have a question.

I have three tables table1, table2, table3. I am trying to display emailIds from table1. First displaying rows from table1 in ascending order of emailIds which are mapped in table3 and then displaying remaining rows from table1 which are not present in table3 in ascending order of emailIds.

Here is table structure:

table1 columns

```
    id
    emailId
    user
```

table2 columns

```
    id
    aliasemailId
```

table3 columns

```
    table1id -> foreign key table1 id
    table2id -> foreign key table2 id
```

table1 rows

```
        id    emailId         user
        ----- --------------  ------
        1     s_user@xyz.com  user1
        2     w_user@xyz.com  user2
        3     a_user@xyz.com  user3
        4     v_user@xyz.com  user4
        5     x_user@xyz.com  user5
        6     e_user@xyz.com  user6
        7     g_user@xyz.com  user7
        8     k_user@xyz.com  user8
        9     l_user@xyz.com  user9
        10    t_user@xyz.com  user10
```

table2 rows

```
        id    aliasemailId
        ----- -----------------
        1     alias1@xyz.com
        2     alias2@xyz.com
        3     alias3@xyz.com
```

table3 rows

```
        table2id table1id
        -------- ----------
        1        10
        1        3
        1        7
        2        10
        3        4
```

I want to get the list of emailIds in the following format.

1. list all the emailIds from table1 using table3's table2id in ascending order.
2. list all the emailIds from table1 in ascending order. Excluding ids from the step 1.

Final output of the result should look like: for table2id - 1 and excluding of id 1 from table 1

```
        id    emailId         user
        ----- --------------  ------
        3     a_user@xyz.com  user3 (from table 3)
        7     g_user@xyz.com  user7 (from table 3)
        10    t_user@xyz.com  user10 (from table 3)
        6     e_user@xyz.com  user6 (from table 1)
        8     k_user@xyz.com  user8 (from table 1)
        9     l_user@xyz.com  user9 (from table 1)
        1     s_user@xyz.com  user1 (from table 1)
        4     v_user@xyz.com  user4 (from table 1)
        2     w_user@xyz.com  user2 (from table 1)
        5     x_user@xyz.com  user5 (from table 1)
```

I want to know if there is a way to achieve this using criteria builder. Please let me know how can I display this.

Any help is appreciated.

Update:

Is there a way to create a temporary table for a session.? so that the data can be inserted in to temp table and vanishes temp table after the session.

Update 2:

I have tried using the following MySQL query: which give me the values but the result is incorrect.

```
 (Select * from table1 where id in (SELECT table1id FROM table2 where table2id=1) order by emailid) union distinct (select * from table1 order by emailid) limit 30 offset 0
```

Comment: Typically unless you are looking to only write SQL, you write code from the perspective of the domain class and not from table/column names.  This is emphasized in that HQL and HibernateCriteriaBuilder refer to domain property names.  Also, I can't make out what your goal is; none of the final output given uses any of the 'alias' emails, so what is the purpose of that table?

Comment: This is existing implementation and this table is used to find emails in alias and notify actual users.